# Proper implementation for string find() function?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to push doubles to a stack given a string from stdin and until EOF. The string can be composed of doubles, ints, chars, and single spaces.

Currently, I'm utilizing the substring and find() function to account for the whitespace. It works most of the time, but for various input in which a single int is being read (exhibited below), the find() function appears to be clobbering any trailing char.

I've tried to use a variety of the different string functions to try and re-implement the way that I parse the input -- none of which has been successful.

```
while(std::getline(std::cin, string, '\n')){

 for(unsigned int x = 0; x < string.size(); x++){

   std::cout << "You read " << string[x] << std::endl;

   if(isdigit(string[x])){
     do{
      // Get the number, stopping at the first instance of ws
      std::string get_str = string.substr(x, string.find(' '));
      std::cout << "You're converting " << get_str << std::endl;

      // Convert it to a double
      double num = stod(get_str);
      std::cout << "You pushed " << number << std::endl;

      // Push it to the stack
      stack.push(number);

      // Get the new increment
      std::cout << "The size is " << get_str.size() << std::endl;
      x+= get_str.size();
     } while(string[x] >= '0' && string[x] <= '9');
   }
   /* else, do other things... */
```

Given an input of

```
100 200 + 2 /
```

The output is:

```
You read 1
You're converting 100
You pushed 100
The size is 3
You read 2
You're converting 200
You pushed 200
The size is 3
You read +
You read  
You read 2
You're converting 2 /
You pushed 2
The size is 3
```

Specifically, I am wondering why the 3rd to last line `'You're converting 2 / '` includes the '/' when I had utilized `string.find(' ')` in my code as a delimiter. And given this issue, how would I be able to fix it so that only 2 is 'converted'?

Any assistance and feedback is appreciated!

Comment: You might want to read [a `std::stod` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof). It actually have an argument which will "return" the number of characters it read and parsed, which can be used both for validation and to skip characters in the string. That is, you don't have to use `find` or `substr`.

Comment: First, don't call your variable `string`, as that just adds confusion.  Second, you don't need a lot of this code to parse on the space:  `std::istringstream strm(s); std::string token; while (s >> token) { // you have the full token -- determine what it is }` -- That little bit of code takes care of the entire parsing on a space.  You don't need `substr` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

The one parameter [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) will start the search at the beginning of the string, and return an index of the matched character.  The second parameter to [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) is a count of characters.  Put those together with your input and you get a substring with 3 characters.